# Не работает прошивка STM32F746IG

Tags: ассемблер, arm, stm32

Помогите найти проблему? Пытаюсь запрограммировать пин G0, просто, чтобы горел. Программу пишу в sublime-text, компилирую через arm-toolchain, зашиваю программу на STM32F746IG через Flash Loader Demonstrator от STM32. Проверяю пин мультиметром, сигнала нет. В чём может быть проблема?

```
.equ RCC, 0x40023800
.equ RCC_CR, 0x40023800
.equ RCC_PLLCFGR, 0x40023804
.equ RCC_CFGR, 0x40023808
.equ RCC_CIR, 0x4002380C
.equ RCC_AHB1RSTR, 0x40023810
.equ RCC_AHB2RSTR, 0x40023814
.equ RCC_AHB3RSTR, 0x40023818
.equ RCC_APB1RSTR, 0x40023820
.equ RCC_APB2RSTR, 0x40023824
.equ RCC_AHB1ENR, 0x40023830
.equ RCC_AHB2ENR, 0x40023834
.equ RCC_AHB3ENR, 0x40023838
.equ RCC_APB1ENR, 0x40023840
.equ RCC_APB2ENR, 0x40023844

.equ GPIOG, 0x40021800
.equ GPIOG_MODER, 0x40021800
.equ GPIOG_OTYPER, 0x40021804
.equ GPIOG_OSPEEDR, 0x40021808
.equ GPIOG_PUPDR, 0x4002180C
.equ GPIOG_IDR, 0x40021810
.equ GPIOG_ODR, 0x40021814
.equ GPIOG_BSRR, 0x40021818
.equ GPIOG_LCKR, 0x4002181C
.equ GPIOG_AFRL, 0x40021820
.equ GPIOG_AFRH, 0x40021824

.syntax unified
.thumb
.cpu cortex-m7

.section .text

.word 0x20060000
.word reset+1
.word main+1
.word loop+1

reset: b main

main:
    LDR R0, =0x40
    LDR R1, =RCC_AHB1ENR
    STR R0, [R1]

    LDR R0, =0x01
    LDR R1, =GPIOG_MODER
    STR R0, [R1]

    LDR R0, =0x00
    LDR R1, =GPIOG_OTYPER
    STR R0, [R1]

    LDR R0, =0x00
    LDR R1, =GPIOG_OSPEEDR
    STR R0, [R1]

    LDR R0, =0x00
    LDR R1, =GPIOG_PUPDR
    STR R0, [R1]

    LDR R0, =0x01
    LDR R1, =GPIOG_ODR
    STR R0, [R1]

loop: b loop

.end
```

А вот код линковщика

```
MEMORY {
       FLASH(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x100000
       SRAM(WAIL) : ORIGIN = 0x20010000, LENGTH = 0x50000
}
SECTIONS { 
    .text : {
        KEEP(*(.text));
    } > FLASH
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас имеется ряд ошибок, связанных с тем, что вы, возможно, попытались взять готовый код, предназначенный для другого устройства, и адаптировать его под свой контроллер.

Для начала посмотрим на скрипт линкера. В нём неверно обозначены адреса flash-памяти и оперативной памяти. Flash-память должна иметь адрес `0x08000000`, оперативная память должна иметь адрес `0x20000000`. Доступную длину регионов памяти уточните в документации на ваш контроллер. По обозначенному вами адресу `0x00000000` в микроконтроллерах семейства stm32 распологается загрузочное ПЗУ, в котором хранится код, предназначенный для обслуживания подсистем самого контроллера, и он недоступен для модификации пользователем.

Теперь смотрим ваш код. Согласно ABI, в начале исполняемого файла должна находиться таблица векторов прерываний и она у вас имеется, но не совсем правильная.

```
.word 0x20060000 ;Stack pointer
.word reset+1    ;Reset handler
.word main+1     ;NMI handler
.word loop+1     ;HardFault handler
```

На первом месте должен находиться указатель стека. Указатель стека должен быть действительным адресом в оперативной памяти. Вы же написали там адрес `0x20060000`, который, судя по вашему коду линкера, находится за пределами доступной области оперативной памяти. Обычно указателем стека назначают последнее доступное машинное слово, и при использовании стека он будет расти вниз. То есть, вы можете указать адрес `0x2004fffc`, разумеется, если вы уточнили размер оперативной памяти контроллера, и он действительно равен `0x50000`. Остальные указатели обработчиков прерываний записаны верно, однако было бы лучше прописать NMI handler по адресу `reset+1`.

Теперь смотрим сам исполняемый код. Процесс записи значений в периферийные регистры у вас происходит правильно, но их содержание я не проверял. Тут нужно долго разбираться с документацией. Я советую вам, во-первых, сверить с документацией адреса всех периферийных регистров, а во-вторых, уточнить, правильные ли значения вы в них записываете.

UPD: судя по тому, что у вас есть ошибки в адресах памяти скрипта линкера, я посоветовал бы ещё проверить в настройках программатора, действительно ли вы записываете программу по адресу `0x08000000`.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Время будет, перепроверю и перепишу код, а так большое спасибо!

Comment: Год спустя проверил всё-таки. Вы были правы в моих ошибках. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Daniil, тогда отметьте ответ как принятый (галочка слева от ответа).